# Mapping breaks my domain class

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

When I add the following mapping to my domain class, I get an error. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong here?

### Domain Class

```
package sample

class Todo {


    String name
    String note
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    Date dueDate
    Date lastModifiedDate
    Date completedDate
    String priority
    String status = "Started"
    User owner
    Category category

    static belongsTo = [User, Category]

    static constraints = {
        name (blank:false)
        priority()
        status()
        note (maxSize:1000, nullable:true)
        completedDate(nullable:true)
        dueDate(nullable:true)
    }

    String toString() {
        name
    }
```

}

### Mapping I Want to Add

```
static mapping = {
    table 'todo-tbl'

    columns {
        name column: 'name-str'
        note column: 'note-str'
    }
    cache true
}
```

### Error I Get When Adding Mapping

> Error 500: Internal Server Error URI /sample/todo/list Class
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException Message Table "TODO" not found; SQL
>   statement: select this_.id as id72_0_, this_.version as version72_0_,
>   this_.category_id as category3_72_0_, this_.completed_date as
>   completed4_72_0_, this_.date_created as date5_72_0_, this_.due_date as
>   due6_72_0_, this_.last_modified_date as last7_72_0_,
>   this_.last_updated as last8_72_0_, this_.name-str as name9_72_0_,
>   this_.note-str as note10_72_0_, this_.owner_id as owner11_72_0_,
>   this_.priority as priority72_0_, this_.status as status72_0_ from
>   todo-tbl this_ limit ? [42102-164]

Comment: Is that a typo in your column mapping for "note" where you have "not"?

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixing that now. I fixed that in the code and I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: It looks like hibernate can't find that table on the DB. Do you have dbCreate set to create-drop?

Comment: I haven't touched any of the database configs outside of this mapping. Where would I find dbCreate?

Comment: dbCreate is inside grails-app/conf/Datasource.groovy

Comment: Thank you. I found that, but I also just solved my issue.

Comment: @oxym0r0n Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Apparently using the hyphen in the table name was a big no-no. This stopped the table from being created in the DB.

Changed

```
table "todo-tbl"
```

to

```
table "todoTbl
```

Comment: Yeah, GORM has a bunch of behaviors around table and column naming.  I have run into issues like this several times.  I've learned to stick with simple, camelcase naming and don't even use keywords as part of the name.